# PS4 - 3 fast bleeps during some games

Tags: ps4

My PS4 makes bleeping noises during some games (it may occur in all games and I've not noticed?)

It's 3 fast bleeps, then silence for anything between 5 and 30 secoonds.

There's no indication of *anything* happening on screen, or in any menus.

Any idea what it is? From reading online I've seen explanations such as it's over heating, which it doesn't seem to be (and it's never crashed from such, and the fans aren't doing over time as they do when I play certain games) to the fact it's failed to do a online upload of a save.

Comment: Does it do this on digital games exclusively, or does it also do it on discs? I only ask because three quick beeps is usually an indication of it trying to eject a disc when no disc is inserted.

Comment: Fluttershy is correct. Triple beeps can also occur when the console fails to shut down properly, it will triple beep; this can't be the case for you though, since it's while playing games.

Comment: ooo sometimes it randomly ejects anyway! that must be why then.... which leads to my next question, how do i stop it :/